# Is it possible to get facebook user id and password from cookies?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cookies, titanium-mobile

I think that browsers store user authentificaton ids and passwords in cookies. If this is always true i don't know if they all share the same folder on systems where to stores these cookies.

My specific problem lies on mobiles OS (currently iOS and soon Android). i think browsers bahviour would be the same on any system (the same on mobile or pc)

I'm developping an app with Titanium which has a module for dealing with cookies but i don't know where to find the facebook cookie on user's system nor how to access it.

Any solution with javascript is also good for me.

Can someone tells us if this is possible to do and how ?

Comment: passwords are not stored in cookies...

Comment: so where? are they secured and inaccessible ?

Comment: Yes - more reading here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9455/is-it-safe-to-store-the-password-hash-in-a-cookie-and-use-it-for-remember-me-l